# Importing a large number of complex matrices from a .DAT file and then numerically analyzing them one by one

Tags: matrix, import, fortran

I have a .DAT file generated by Fortran in which I have data for $2 \times 2$ matrices. For example, the file takes the form (when I open it in the excel):

[image]

I have added a snippet beacause the real variables are too long to type in TeX font. As you can see, each row contains 4 terms, corresponding to an entry in the matrix. Each bracket contains 2 terms because each entry is defined as a complex number; we have a complex matrix at hand.

Now there are about 1500 such entries in the file. Each entry correspond to a distinct time for which the matrix has been calculated. I want to do the following and I am not sure how to do the following steps:

For a specific time, say $t = 0$ (first entry), get the $2 \times 2$ matrix. Do some manipulations on them. The manipulations are of form: multiplying the matrix with 2 other matrices (twice) to get 2 scalar functions (one from each set of multiplication); taking the difference of the 2 scalar functions; and numerically optimizing the difference and get the optimized values of the inputs. I then want to repeat the analysis for all the other entries (matrices) in the file.

How does one go about doing such analysis in *Mathematica?* I'm clueless on this front. I know how to import one real matrix. I don't know how to import one **complex** matrix; and how to recursively import matrices from different rows and do the analysis on each matrix seperately.

If I know how to approach the problem, I can tackle it and then post additional questions with codes and related problems.

P.S: Please do suggest any other appropriate tag, if any.

---

**Edit:**

Using

```
Import["FILEPATH", "Table"]
```

here are the first few entries in the imported list:

```
{{( 0.70992637972979133     ,  0.0000000000000000     ), 
 ( 0.34768150998932623     ,-0.29148928933886220     ), 
  ( 0.34768150998932623     , 0.29148928933886220     ), 
   ( 0.29007362027020861     ,  0.0000000000000000     )},        {0.71578138101774014     ,  0.0000000000000000     ), (
 0.34162400932308312     ,-0.29395228624439607     ), (
    0.34162400932308312     , 0.29395228624439607     ), (
        0.28421861898225981     ,  0.0000000000000000     )}}
```

Fullform is:

```
 List[List["( 0.70992637972979133     ,  0.0000000000000000     )","(   0.347"\[Ellipsis] "0     )",""\[Ellipsis] "","( 0.29007362027020861     ,  0.0000000000000000     )"],\[LeftSkeleton]1500\[RightSkeleton]]
```

Comment: Well, you may try to import it in a real way, then use Map or Apply to create a complex matrix, then in advance uae these two functions and friends to accomplish your goal. And please supply a basic example dataset.

Comment: @Wjx how do I upload a sample .DAT file in my post? I see no such option.

Comment: copy your import result.

Comment: @Wjx, I am getting extra commas when I copy the imported list. What should I do?

Comment: @Wjx I manually removed them for a ridiculously small data set, I hope it's usable.

Comment: Can you post the `FullForm` of these first entries `Import["FILEPATH", "Table"]//FullForm//Short`

Comment: @Saner Here it is: `List[List["( 0.70992637972979133     ,  0.0000000000000000     )","(   0.347"\[Ellipsis] "0     )",""\[Ellipsis] "","( 0.29007362027020861     ,  0.0000000000000000     )"],\[LeftSkeleton]1500\[RightSkeleton]]` As you can see, I had to remove...

Comment: the commas on my own.

Comment: see if my answer gets you somewhere

Comment: @Sander, okay, I'll do that once I have generated new data for my problem. How would your approach allow me to do all the manipulations (matrix multiplication, numerical optimization etc.) for each matrix in the list? Don't I need to run some sort of do loop that does all the operations by picking each matrix from the list one by one?

Comment: You may try ReadList

Comment: not sure what you need but see updated answer for inspiration

Comment: @Sander Thanks. I didn't know of this approach. Let me crunch the data for my problem and if I face any issue, I'll get back over here with more details of the types of manipulations I intend to do.

Comment: can you modify the fortran? You might seperately write the real/imaginary parts and so make it easier/faster to read.

Comment: @george2079  Any idea how to do that? Fortran by default gives the output like this.

Comment: for example `write(unit,*)real(matrix)` then `write(unit,*)aimag(matrix)`. As you read it in you need to take every other line and do `complexresult=line1+ I line2`.  Its a bit cumbersome but not as bad as having to do string operations.

Comment: @george2079 I don't know understand how to ask mathematica to add lines while importing?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading `Strings`. So please review if `Import` option settings are correct. There is a whole range of formats for tabular, database and spreadsheet files. If you are sure this is as good as it gets:

```
input=Import["FILEPATH", "Table"];
```

I would first split the `Strings` at the round brackets:

```
firstpass=StringSplit[input, "(" | ")"];
```

Then replace the text strings with actual expressions (values). You should now have a list structure with values (check this with `FullForm`):

```
secondpass = ToExpression[firstpass];
```

This may be what you need, i.e. a list of 2x2 matrices; but if dimensionality is still not correct, do this:

```
thirdpass=Partition[Flatten[secondpass],{2,2}]
```

This will restructure your flat list into a series of 2x2 matrices. You may need to fiddle this a bit as I don't have the file so could not test it on your data.

So let's assume you get your list of 2x2 matrices and want to manipulate these. First I create a random matrix list with the same format:

```
fourthpass = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2, 2}];
```

**UPDATE:**
The rest is speculation, as you do not specifiy what you want to do, however this may be applicable for manipulating several matrices, e.g. matrix multiplication of two subsequent matrices:

```
FoldList[#1 #2 &, IdentityMatrix[2], fourthpass]//Rest;
```

or perhaps raising the entire list to the third power

```
MatrixPower[#,3]&/@fourthpass;
```

or

```
myownoptimizationfunction[#]&/@fourthpass;
```

In general, you do not need loop constructs. The above is more straigtforward and often faster.